# Update Command Mysteriously not working in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access-2007

I have an ASP.NET application in which I'll be updating some notes, however the command won't update the database notes. It did it once and then decided not to do it anymore. No changes were made between in not working, working once and then not working again. Very odd situation... here's the code. I can't find anything wrong with it.

```
protected void saveNotes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string theNotes = notes.InnerText;
     string[] vars = { "@notes", "@jobNumber" };
     string[] vals = { theNotes, jobNumber };
     HelperMethods.OleDB_Query("UPDATE [Jobs] SET Notes = @notes WHERE Job_Number = @jobNumber", vars, vals);

     test.InnerText = theNotes;
}
```

I display the notes in the aspx page to verify that they do indeed populate and they do.

Here's the database access code:

```
public static void OleDB_Query(string cmd, string[] vars = null, string[] vals = null)
{
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(cmd, Connection);
    if (vars != null) {
        for (int k = 0; k < vars.Length; k++)
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(vars[k], vals[k]);
        Command.Connection.Open();
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Command.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to display the job number and notes on each update attempt.

I'm getting the job number via URL query string. If the job number starts with a zero, then the zeros are all parsed off and and what's displayed is the notes text followed by the parsed job number. If the job number doesn't start with a zero, only the job number is displayed. Makes no sense whatsoever. It's a very basic setup that I've done many times in the past. It's just deciding not to work anymore for some odd reason.

Comment: Once I break down and ask the question on here, I find the answer... maybe...

Comment: where is jobNumber being populated?

Comment: I'm passing the string through the URL query string

Comment: So, have you tried the obvious steps of verifying that the Job_Number column in the DB actually contains what you expect it to? What about the parsing code that actually generates your jobNumber class member?

Comment: I'm using the exact same method to change the item's status or delete it. Those methods work fine. I'm opening this new window in greybox, but I don't see how that should matter as I've done that in the past.

Comment: If I manually insert the data into the database and then type in the URL with the query string portion or even go to the page via my application, the text populates. It just won't save new data, except for one time when it decided it'd let one slip through.

Comment: Does ExecuteNonQuery() return 0? That means that no rows matched your criteria.

Comment: Andleer's comment-question is what I've been trying to get from you - there seems to be a mismatch, particularly since you have a problem with the `notes.InnerText` being empty....

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's related to not disposing of the connection and commands properly. Update your static helper method to use `using` statements and it should ensure your connections and commands are being cleaned up and ready for the next use.

```
public static void OleDB_Query(string cmd, string[] vars = null, string[] vals = null)
{
    using(OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        Command.Connection.Open();
        using(OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(cmd, Connection))
        {
            if (vars != null) {
                for (int k = 0; k < vars.Length; k++)
                    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(vars[k], vals[k]);

                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        Command.Connection.Close();            
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot! Thank you!!

Comment: It's still an improvement to the method, but this sounds like a straightforward parsing / column contents mismatch...

Comment: Bummer. I suggest you wrap all IDisposable objects in using statements though to prevent other resource issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Brian. I'll do that!

Answer (score 0):

Could this have to do with the fact that you are passing your `Job_Number` as a string? What is the underlying sql datatype? If it is a `char` or `varchar`, stripping off the leading zeros will produce a different `Job_Number`.

Consider parsing your `QueryString` value to an `int` before passing it to SQL which will strip all leading zeros.

Comment: I want to keep the leading zeros. That's the issue. The data column is assigned as a text format. When it displays the job number on my main page, the leading zeros are there.

Comment: What is the underlying SQL datatype?

Answer (score 0):

TWO PROBLEMS (ONE SOLVED, ONE SORT OF SOLVED):

SOLVED:

The data wasn't being inputted into the database because the jobNumber variable was being reset on each page load. I tried stopping in by using (!IsPostBack) but then the variable had no value. Since it seemed to be losing its value somehow I just stuck it in ViewState and I was able to successfully update the database.

UNSOLVED (BUT WORK AROUND FOUND) PROBLEM:

When I pass a job number without leading zeros, everything works just fine and dandy. However, when I pass a job number with leading zeros, the query string parses it and I'm left with a job number that is incorrect. I tested the variable just before passing it across the url and just after. It's being parsed in the url. Anyone know anything about this? I'm thinking I'll just pass an extra variable which represents the number of leading zeros so I can stick 'em back on.

Comment: So, when you got pageNumber from the query string, how are you doing that? (checking my backlogged questions and flags)